# Permission Denied when editing alternatives for java jdk

Tags: java, linux, centos

So, On CentOS 7 via putty I'm trying to update my Java as it is currently 1.6.0.

I have installed the correct JDK however I now have to edit the alternatives and when attempting to do so I receive this:

```
[mcserver@e3-1240v3 ~]$ alternatives --config java

There are 5 programs which provide 'java'.

Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
  2           /opt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java
* 3           /usr/java/jdk-10.0.1/bin/java
  4           /usr/java/jre-10.0.1/bin/java
  5           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_172-amd64/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 3
failed to create /var/lib/alternatives/java.new: Permission denied
```

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either `sudo` the command, or change the permissions (`chmod`) for the `/var/lib/alternatives` directory and eventually create it if it does not exist